# Add a field to the Find Duplicates search

Tags: javascript, leads, duplicate-management

I'm re-creating our Find Duplicates button on the lead object, and was wondering if there's a way to add an additional field to this search (beyond Name, Last Name, Company, Email, Email Domain, and Phone).

To add to this, is there a way to also specify a 'soft' or 'fuzzy' search to the fields selected? (e.g. when searching for company name, I want to account for a company name that may be 'Company XYZ LLC' on one record and 'Company XYZ L.L.C.' in another record.)

The code I have so far is as follows (specifying pre-checked fields applicable for search):

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/23.0/connection.js")} 
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}"; 

var l = new sforce.SObject("Lead"); 
l.id = "{!Lead.Id}"; 


var result = sforce.connection.update([l]); 

if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) 
{ 
// Refresh window 
window.location = "/lead/leadmergewizard.jsp?retURL=%2F{!Lead.Id}&id={!Lead.Id}&p1=0&p2=0&p3=1&p4=1&p5=0&p6=1"; 
} 
else 
{ 
alert("Error saving lead. Please check for validation rules that may be preventing you from saving the record — e.g., missing Total Power Units"); 
}
```